# the notation of ``infinitly close to'' a point

Tags: notation

I seems to be taught before that in $\int_{a^+}^{b^-} f(x)dx$, the notation of $b^-$ mean a point infinitly close to x=b point from the left. Similarly for the $a^+$ (from the right). Am I right? if yes, what's the name of this notation rule? If not, what's the correct notations? Thanks!

Comment: When you write this integral, do you mean a Riemann integral?

Comment: It's impossible for one real number to be "infinitely close" to another different real number.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such thing as  a point infinitely close to another point.

I've never seen the notation $\int_{a^+}^{b^-}$. If I did see that notation I can't imagine what it would mean other than $\int_a^b$. The notation $a^{\pm}$ comes up in *limits*, not integrals! $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ means the right-hand limit of $f$ at $a$.

The notation can be misleading. In particular, the $x\to a^+$ does *not* mean that $x$ is approaching some number $a^+$; you should  parse it as $(x\to a)^+$, not  $x\to(a^+)$.

(**Ok**, I thought of what the notation $\int_{a^+}^{b^-}$ might  mean. Maybe it means $$\lim_{\alpha\to a^+}\lim_{\beta\to b^-}\int_\alpha^\beta.)$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding + above a number in limit means that we are approaching that value from positive side( right side) whereas - means approaching from left side.